# Is "oeuf à la coque" slang for "soldier" or "idiot"?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, argot

This is taken from the first paragraph of Céline's *Voyage au bout de la nuit* (Journey to the End of the Night). I was dubious about it, since I was told this author had a very slangy style (and this novel was released in 1932 but it's set during WWI). I'm comparing the original version to the English translation. Consider *les oeufs à la coque* literally means "hard-boiled eggs".

Original version:

> Ça a débuté comme ça. Moi, j’avais jamais rien dit. Rien. C’est Arthur
>   Ganate qui m’a fait parler. Arthur, un étudiant, un carabin lui aussi,
>   un camarade. On se rencontre donc place Clichy. C’était après le
>   déjeuner. Il veut me parler. Je l’écoute. « Restons pas dehors ! qu’il
>   me dit. Rentrons ! » Je rentre avec lui. Voilà. « Cette terrasse,
>   qu’il commence, c’est pour **les oeufs à la coque** ! Viens par ici ! »
>   Alors, on remarque encore qu’il n’y avait personne dans les rues, à
>   cause de la chaleur ; pas de voitures, rien.

English version:

> Here's how it started. I'd never said a word. Not one word. It was
>   Arthur Ganate that made me speak up. Arthur was a friend from med
>   school. So we meet on the Place Clichy. It was after breakfast. He
>   wants to talk to me. I listen. "Not out here," he says. "Let's go in."
>   We go in. And there we were. "This terrace," he says, "is for **jerks**.
>   Come on over there." Then we see that there's not a soul in the
>   street, because of the heat; no cars, nothing.

Now, the next sentence mentions nobody is on the street because of the heat, so considering the context I don't know if *les oeufs à la coque* is referring to the fact the day is so hot you could boil eggs on the terrace or that the terrace is a place that certain type of people frequent, maybe it means "idiots" (jerks) or maybe it could mean "soldier" (the story is about a soldier, so perhaps a "hard-boiled egg" is army slang for soldier, a reference to the shell being the helmet). Was it properly translated? What do you think?

Comment: La question a été posée il y a quelques années [sur WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C5%93ufs-%C3%A0-la-coque.2667888/). Les gens ont émis plusieurs hypothèses et il n'y a pas de conclusion qui s'impose.

Comment: Could it simply be a way to say that the terrace is really hot, and that you're "getting cooked" like an _oeuf à la coque_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le français, comme sans doute d’autres langues, possède des expressions qui combinent des situations mal à propos à des circonstances ou des entités pour lesquelles ces conditions seraient mieux appropriées :

- **Il pleut il mouille, c’est la fête à la grenouille** → comptine enfantine qui illustre l’envers du proverbe plus général ***Le bonheur des uns fait le malheur des autres***.
- **un vent à écorner les bœufs** → il vente assez pour que les mouches n’embêtent pas si l’on veut écorner des bœufs, mais il vente assez pour que certaines activités soient difficiles *(jouer au tennis)*, désagréables *(s’aventurer dans un blizzard)* ou même dangereuses *(partir en bateau sur une mer démontée)*.

Dans un registre plus catégoriquement négatif...

- **Mais c’est du (communisme/capitalisme/sensationalisme/clientélisme/...) !** → s’utilise pour insinuer que l’on reconnaît une certaine philosophie ou idéologie comme existante et ayant ses adeptes, mais que l’on y adhère nullement, et qu’au contraire on la rejette sous toutes ses formes, aussi diluées soient-elles. Ces idées seraient *bonnes pour les adhérents du ...-isme*. On trouve un exemple similaire peu après la citation mentionnée dans le texte de Céline : **T’es un anarchiste et puis voilà tout !**
- **C’est bon pour les vidanges/les orties** → ça fera très bien, ce sera parfaitement à sa place, avec ce qui est (devenu) indésirable.

Dans ce qui suit, j’entends montrer qu’il y a sur la terrasse *« la fête aux œufs à la coque »,* plutôt qu’une *« bande d’œufs à la coque »* bipèdes assise aux tables.

---

#### Céline et ses œufs à la coque

On pourrait au premier abord penser que la terrasse n’est bonne qu’à la consommation de petits déjeuners, personnifiés ici par des œufs à la coque, mais que pour la consommation d’alcool qu’envisagent potentiellement les étudiants, l’intérieur du café conviendra mieux. Mais rien dans le texte ne valide par la suite cette interprétation.

On apprend par contre dès la phrase suivante que la température ce jour-là est désagréablement élevée, et la suite élabore à ce sujet. On peut donc en effet penser que la température sur la terrasse est peut-être plus appropriée aux œufs à la coque qu’aux deux étudiants, qui s’installeront donc à l’intérieur du café.

Il nous resterait maintenant à savoir si oui ou non il y a des gens sur ladite terrasse. L’auteur ne nous renseigne pas à ce sujet...

Dans l’affirmative, on assimilerait en effet ces gens à des œufs à la coque, ce qui serait déjà bien condescendant si ce n’était carrément injurieux, à cause de la sémantique de l’œuf ***(faire l’œuf*** → faire l’imbécile, ***une tête d’œuf*** → un idiot) et possiblement en sautant de l’œuf à l’oiseau, réputé peu futé par diverses expressions courantes ***(avoir une cervelle d’oiseau/de moineau, avoir une tête de linotte, être bête comme une oie).***

Mais il me semble que cette chaleur étouffante que ressentent les deux étudiants est aussi ressentie par les Parisiens en général, puisque l’on sait par la suite que les rues sont désertes, et que vraisemblablement la terrasse est donc vide. En ce cas, le texte de Céline serait à comprendre comme l’expression d’une chaleur intense sur la terrasse, appropriée aux œufs à la coque, pas à l’existence humaine.

On pourrait aussi penser que l’affirmation soit émise comme l’expression d’une réalité intemporelle, c’est-à-dire que tout client de la terrasse, même un autre jour où la température y serait plus douce, serait un œuf à la coque. Je ne le crois pas. Ce serait une image très forcée, une affirmation gratuite, et ça ferait bien peu de cas de l’interprétation bien plus simple présentée au paragraphe précédent.

---

#### Ma conclusion

Je crois que le traducteur en a trop et pas assez fait : il a conclu que par les œufs à la coque, on désignait les gens installés à la terrasse, et il a fait disparaître avec son *jerk* le très important lien avec la chaleur, qui jouera un rôle pendant un moment de la conversation entre les deux étudiants.

Comment: I agree with you & @Arkeen about it being a [neutral] reference to the stifling heat & not a negative value judgment aimed at anyone **fool**hardy enough to subject themselves to such a heat (nor a positive one aimed at anyone hardy enough to endure/support/enjoy it). I think it’s just as if it had been a bitterly cold day & Arthur had used: “… c’est pour les glaces à l'eau/les canards/les oeufs à la neige!” to refer to how cold it is, with no offense intended to anyone (but using “c’est pour les esquimaux” to express this, regardless of intent, would, imo, be offensive, at least in English).

Answer (score 4):

En ancien argot faire l’œuf désigne faire l'imbécile, par opposition a l'expression contemporaine tête d’œuf qui désigne un intellectuel.

Dans la même œuvre on peut en trouver un exemple:

> « Léon, qu'on lui a dit le matin où il débutait, fais pas l’œuf dans ta nouvelle place ! Te fais pas repérer pour tes idées à la manque... »

Source : [https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_l’œuf](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_l%E2%80%99%C5%93uf)

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert, but I think the translation is wrong. I never heard "oeuf à la coque" as a synonym for jerks. Maybe it was something that people used to say back then, but here again, it would be the first time I hear that.
So I also think the expression is used because of the heat, because characters are "baking" (or "being baked") outside, and this expression is really common for being hot.

Answer (score 1):

From Celine point-of-view,
 *oeuf à la coque*, was ... 
a jerk. I'm not sure if he meant "a upper-middle class man" ? Or a "lesser-middle classe man"
(Sorry I'm french, and I can't figure out what he meant (deprecated maybe ?)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's, in the point of view of Celine's narrator : a jerk, I think.